# DynamoDB table was created for storing checkpoints

Tags: spark-streaming, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to run a trivial steaming application on AWS EMR.
In my local machine, everything works as expected.
However, when I'm running my example in AWS EMR cluster, I'm getting empty RDDs.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "1.14.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "3.0.0"
```

There is no DynamoDB table was created for storing checkpoints.
Spark version: 3.2.1
EMR release: 6.7.0

**(EDIT)** After placing guava-31.0.1-jre.jar in /usr/lib/spark/jars/, an empty DynamoDB has been created.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, consider following:

1. check "guava" jar in SPARK jars;
2. verify kinesisCredentials in KinesisInputDStream.builder (use SparkAWSCredentials in kinesisCredentials)